# How to bind an array to a list using SwiftUI

Tags: list, binding, swiftui

I'm trying to bind an array to a list in SwiftUI. I've been struggling to understand how to do this given that I'm quite new to SwiftUI et. al. Here's what I'm trying to:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var results: [MKLocalSearchCompletion]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
            MapSearchBar(text: $text, results: $results)
            List($results) { result in
                Text(result.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Presently getting, `Generic parameter 'SelectionValue' could not be inferred'`, which I understand-ish, but I can't seem to find my way...

I've not yet come across great doco on this, but I'm happy to be pointed at some.

Answer (score 3):

`results` is a binding so you do not need a `read-write binding` in the list parameter. Also, to fix the generic parameter, add an `id`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var results: [MKLocalSearchCompletion]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
            MapSearchBar(text: $text, results: $results)
            List(results, id: \.self) { result in
                Text(result.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That did the trick. Using the `$` for just for read-write now makes complete sense to me.

Comment: I like the `\.self` also. I've not seen that before.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I don't understand the solution since the program looks different than in my case.
I have a sample array of 3 strings called `repository names` inside `Data` class. How can I bind it to a new created list, @sfung3?